# SQL CTE Expression with Cross Join - Can it be simplified?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, join, insert, cte

I am looking to simplify the below SQL Query. Currently it's taking 44 mins to run.
The main issue seems to be the `WHERE [Versions] = (SELECT max([Versions]) from BPC_CTE)` statement.
What I'd like to do is filter out the `[d_bpc]` table data by the `max([Version])`, which would give me a smaller data set to work with, then `CROSS JOIN` it with the `[d_bpcyearmonth]` data.

```
With BPC_CTE ([id] ,[bpc_desc] ,[bpc_active_ingredient] ,[bpc_ai_content] ,[bpc_business_nature]
      ,[bpc_brand] ,[bpc_product_category] ,[bpc_final_fp_code] ,[bpc_formulation_type] ,[bpc_min_pack]
      ,[bpc_npl] ,[bpc_conversion_ratio] ,[bpc_segment] ,[bpc_status] ,[bpc_product_type] ,[bpc_launch_year]
      ,[bpc_scaling] ,[bpc_nbc] ,[bpc_sku] ,[bpc_reporting] ,[bpc_last_update] ,[bpc_latest], [Versions])
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT [idbpc] ,[bpc_desc] ,[bpc_active_ingredient] ,[bpc_ai_content] ,[bpc_business_nature]
      ,[bpc_brand] ,[bpc_product_category] ,[bpc_final_fp_code] ,[bpc_formulation_type] ,[bpc_min_pack]
      ,[bpc_npl] ,[bpc_conversion_ratio] ,[bpc_segment] ,[bpc_status] ,[bpc_product_type] ,[bpc_launch_year]
      ,[bpc_scaling] ,[bpc_nbc] ,[bpc_sku] ,[bpc_reporting] ,[bpc_last_update] ,[bpc_latest], a.[Version]
FROM [dbo].[d_bpc] a
LEFT JOIN [d_bpchilo] b ON b.idhl = a.idbpc
WHERE PATINDEX('%TOTAL%', bpc_reporting) = 0 
      AND bpc_reporting<>'' 
      AND PATINDEX('%_NBC%', idbpc) = 0 
      AND b.idhl IS NULL
)
SELECT * 
FROM BPC_CTE AS BPC_CTE1
CROSS JOIN [dbo].[d_bpcyearmonth]
WHERE [Versions] = (SELECT max([Versions]) from BPC_CTE);
```

I tried running the base query, which took 14 mins without adding the `WHERE [Versions] = (SELECT max([Versions]) from BPC_CTE);` part.

The base query resulted in about 4,000 rows of data. Adding the cross join resulted in about 470,000 rows of data.

In addition to producing this query as a `SELECT DISTINCT` statement, I have now added `INSERT` functionality. Here it is:

```
With BPC_CTE ([idhl] ,[hl_desc] ,[hl_active_ingredient] ,[hl_ai_content] ,[hl_business_nature]
      ,[hl_brand] ,[hl_product_category] ,[hl_final_fp_code] ,[hl_formulation_type] ,[hl_min_pack]
      ,[hl_npl] ,[hl_conversion_ratio] ,[hl_segment] ,[hl_status] ,[hl_product_type] ,[hl_launch_year]
      ,[hl_scaling] ,[hl_nbc] ,[hl_sku] ,[hl_reporting] ,[hl_last_update] ,[hl_latest], [Version])
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT [idbpc] ,[bpc_desc] ,[bpc_active_ingredient] ,[bpc_ai_content] ,[bpc_business_nature]
      ,[bpc_brand] ,[bpc_product_category] ,[bpc_final_fp_code] ,[bpc_formulation_type] ,[bpc_min_pack]
      ,[bpc_npl] ,[bpc_conversion_ratio] ,[bpc_segment] ,[bpc_status] ,[bpc_product_type] ,[bpc_launch_year]
      ,[bpc_scaling] ,[bpc_nbc] ,[bpc_sku] ,[bpc_reporting] ,[bpc_last_update] ,[bpc_latest], a.[Version]
FROM [dbo].[d_bpc] a
LEFT JOIN [d_bpchilo2] b ON b.idhl = a.idbpc
WHERE PATINDEX('%TOTAL%', bpc_reporting) = 0 
      AND bpc_reporting<>'' 
      AND PATINDEX('%_NBC%', idbpc) = 0 
      AND b.idhl IS NULL
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[d_bpchilo2] ([idhl] ,[hl_desc] ,[hl_active_ingredient] ,[hl_ai_content] ,[hl_business_nature]
      ,[hl_brand] ,[hl_product_category] ,[hl_formulation_type] ,[hl_min_pack] ,[hl_conversion_ratio] ,[hl_segment]
      ,[hl_product_type] ,[hl_launch_year] ,[hl_scaling] ,[hl_nbc] ,[hl_sku] ,[hl_reporting] ,[hl_year_month]
      ,[hl_latest] ,[Version] ,[hl_last_update] ,[hl_modified_by])
SELECT [idhl] ,[hl_desc] ,[hl_active_ingredient] ,[hl_ai_content] ,[hl_business_nature] ,[hl_brand] ,[hl_product_category]
      ,[hl_formulation_type] ,[hl_min_pack] ,[hl_conversion_ratio] ,[hl_segment] ,[hl_product_type] ,[hl_launch_year]
      ,[hl_scaling] ,[hl_nbc] ,[hl_sku] ,[hl_reporting] ,[YearMonth] ,[hl_latest] ,[Version] ,[hl_last_update]
      ,'Auto-Update' as [hl_modified_by]
FROM BPC_CTE AS BPC_CTE1
CROSS JOIN [dbo].[d_bpcyearmonth]
WHERE [Version] = (SELECT max([Version]) from BPC_CTE)
;
```

Some people asked about the table structure. Here's the d_bpc table:
The table structure is as follows:

```
USE [DWH]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[d_bpc](
    [idbpc] [nchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [bpc_desc] [nvarchar](120) NULL,
    [bpc_active_ingredient] [nvarchar](120) NULL,
    [bpc_ai_content] [nchar](23) NULL,
    [bpc_business_nature] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [bpc_brand] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [bpc_product_category] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [bpc_final_fp_code] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [bpc_formulation_type] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [bpc_min_pack] [nchar](38) NULL,
    [bpc_npl] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [bpc_conversion_ratio] [nchar](6) NULL,
    [bpc_segment] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [bpc_status] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [bpc_product_type] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [bpc_launch_year] [nchar](4) NULL,
    [bpc_scaling] [nchar](3) NULL,
    [bpc_nbc] [nchar](19) NULL,
    [bpc_sku] [nchar](19) NULL,
    [bpc_reporting] [nchar](19) NULL,
    [bpc_last_update] [datetime] NULL,
    [bpc_latest] [int] NULL,
    [Version] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Many thanks for your help in advance.
BB.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum, please tag your SQL Server version and take a look at: [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: We can only guess without more information. Table structure would use useful, especially what keys and indexes are defined, and approximate row counts. Also the query plans for each example (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ is a useful place to post them rather than dropping the XML or a screenshot here), estimated query plans will do for those queries that seem to run indefinitely but actual plan results are better.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look guys. I'm using SQL Server 14.0.1000.169. Also, I got the query working well but wanted to put the data into a table. I therefore modified the query to accommodate this. Unfortunately, I now receive an error saying data has been truncated. I'll search through the source to see if there's any odd data in it. The Insert functionality may be useful to others too as I couldn't find much on the web re CTE's with Insert statements combined.

Comment: I wonder if the `DISTINCT` is required. if `idbpc` is the PK, it likely isn't.

Comment: Please apply the latest CU. Keeping a server at RTM is cruel and unusual punishment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this; I added a DENSE_RANK() and another CTE to get just the latest version of the data (BEFORE the cross-join).  Although with such a prolific explosion of data (from 4k to 470K rows), I'd be curious if your wait wasn't on tempdb to make enough space.

Still, this should at least prevent querying the BPC_CTE more than once, so might be faster.

```
;With BPC_CTE ([id] ,[bpc_desc] ,[bpc_active_ingredient] ,[bpc_ai_content] ,[bpc_business_nature]
          ,[bpc_brand] ,[bpc_product_category] ,[bpc_final_fp_code] ,[bpc_formulation_type] ,[bpc_min_pack]
          ,[bpc_npl] ,[bpc_conversion_ratio] ,[bpc_segment] ,[bpc_status] ,[bpc_product_type] ,[bpc_launch_year]
          ,[bpc_scaling] ,[bpc_nbc] ,[bpc_sku] ,[bpc_reporting] ,[bpc_last_update] ,[bpc_latest], [Versions], [RN])
    AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT [idbpc] ,[bpc_desc] ,[bpc_active_ingredient] ,[bpc_ai_content] ,[bpc_business_nature]
          ,[bpc_brand] ,[bpc_product_category] ,[bpc_final_fp_code] ,[bpc_formulation_type] ,[bpc_min_pack]
          ,[bpc_npl] ,[bpc_conversion_ratio] ,[bpc_segment] ,[bpc_status] ,[bpc_product_type] ,[bpc_launch_year]
          ,[bpc_scaling] ,[bpc_nbc] ,[bpc_sku] ,[bpc_reporting] ,[bpc_last_update] ,[bpc_latest], a.[Version]
        , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.[Version] ORDER BY a.[Version] DESC)
    FROM [dbo].[d_bpc] a
    LEFT JOIN [d_bpchilo] b ON b.idhl = a.idbpc
    WHERE PATINDEX('%TOTAL%', bpc_reporting) = 0 
          AND bpc_reporting<>'' 
          AND PATINDEX('%_NBC%', idbpc) = 0 
          AND b.idhl IS NULL
    )
    , CTE_LatestBPC AS  
        (
        SELECT [id] ,[bpc_desc] ,[bpc_active_ingredient] ,[bpc_ai_content] ,[bpc_business_nature]
          ,[bpc_brand] ,[bpc_product_category] ,[bpc_final_fp_code] ,[bpc_formulation_type] ,[bpc_min_pack]
          ,[bpc_npl] ,[bpc_conversion_ratio] ,[bpc_segment] ,[bpc_status] ,[bpc_product_type] ,[bpc_launch_year]
          ,[bpc_scaling] ,[bpc_nbc] ,[bpc_sku] ,[bpc_reporting] ,[bpc_last_update] ,[bpc_latest], [Versions]
         FROM BPC_CTE AS B 
         WHERE B.RN = 1
         )
    SELECT * 
    FROM CTE_LatestBPC AS BPC_CTE1
    CROSS JOIN [dbo].[d_bpcyearmonth]
```

Comment: Another option. Modify the original CTE with: `( SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1) WITH TIES ... ORDER BY a.[Version] DESC )`

Comment: thank you, @ypercubeᵀᴹ, I learned something new today.

Comment: Dear All, thanks to those of you who looked at this and gave a helping hand - much appreciated. 

Dear Jonathan Fite: I liked your approach of adding an additional CTE - it worked, but ended up taking 48 mins to run, which was about double the time with only one CTE.

Each of your responses gave me interesting different avenues for thinking avout this problem, so many thanks.

Kind regards, BB.